# can you run an iOS app executable without source code on a Mac, such as in emulator?

Tags: ios, ipad, macos, ios4, app-store

is it possible to download an App Store executable to a jailbroken iPad, then download it to a Mac and make it run there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. An App that runs on the iPad is built for the ARM processor. The emulator however requries an App built for i386 processor. (When you have the source code, XCode builds it for both processors.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  The iPhone simulator runs x86 code, and the iPhone runs ARM code.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no emulator that can run iOS.

Comment: Well, this isn't technically correct -- the iPhone Simulator (I guess now it's called the iOS Simulator) runs iOS, just an X86 version of it.

Comment: Yes, but it's a simulator, not an emulator, that's an important difference when it comes to running compiled iOS apps.

Comment: Fair enough; I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. An iOS app must be compiled for the i386 platform in order to be executable under the simulator. So, an app downloaded from the App Store will not run, since it is compiled for the iPhone native processor (arm).